# use rsync in contribute mode for syncing files

Tags: rsync

What's the rsync options that will set it up in a contribute mode, i.e.: files from source can only update the destination, not overwrite or deletion. Say, I have a picture folder in my source which has the recent picture, and the destination has all the pictures I ever have. I just want to get the source to destination with new pictures. How do I do this?
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, I guess you can use the "-u" option.

```
   -u, --update
          This  forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destina-
          tion and have a modified time that  is  newer  than  the  source
          file.   (If an existing destination file has a modification time
          equal to the source file’s, it will be updated if the sizes  are
          different.)
```